# NSWindow not closing when created with custom NSApplication

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow

I'm creating my own subclass of NSApplication, and am running into a roadblock. Here is my implementation of the `run()` method.

```
override func run() {
    finishLaunching()
    repeat {

        let event = nextEventMatchingMask(0xfffffffffffffff, untilDate: NSDate.distantPast(), inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode, dequeue: true)
        if event != nil { sendEvent(event!) }
        updateWindows()

    } while true

}
```

In my `main.swift` I have this:

```
let myApp: MyApplication = MyApplication.sharedApplication() as! MyApplication

let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask , backing: .Buffered, defer: false)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

myApp.run()
```

The reason why I have `0xfffffffffffffff` instead of `Int(NSEventMask.AnyEventMask.rawValue)` is because the latter overflows when converted from `UInt64` to `Int`.

The problem is, when I click on the red close button, the window does not close, and when I select "Quit" from the dock icon menu, it does not quit. Why does this happen?

EDIT: The same problem is discussed in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665052/4282669%22this%20answer%22)

EDIT 2: I've created an objective-c version of this code, and everything works fine. I suspect the problem is that I can't use NSAnyEventMask in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem, In Objective-C I can just use this, and my app will respond to the quit item in the dock menu.

```
NSEvent *event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask 
                                    untilDate:nil 
                                       inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                                      dequeue:YES];
```

In Swift if you try to get the next event like that you would do this:

```
let event = nextEventMatchingMask(Int(NSEventMask.AnyEventMask.rawValue),
                                  untilDate: NSDate.distantPast(), 
                                  inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode, 
                                  dequeue: true)
```

However, you get an overflow error when converting from UInt64 to Int. This seems to be unintended. At first, I tried to resolve this problem by replacing it with `0xfffffffffffffff`. This worked fine, and the app would respond to events. But this was not enough, actually. The app needs to also respond to events matching a mask `0x1`. I have no idea why, but this allows me to quit and hide my app from the dock menu. (`0x0` only allows me to quit.)

So then, the entire `run()` implementation of a Swift NSApplication subclass is this:

```
override func run() {
    finishLaunching()
    setValue(true, forKey: "running")

    while true {
        let event = nextEventMatchingMask(0xfffffffffffffff, untilDate: NSDate.distantPast(), inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode, dequeue: true)
        let dockEvent = nextEventMatchingMask(0x1, untilDate: NSDate.distantPast(), inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode, dequeue: true)

        if dockEvent != nil { sendEvent(dockEvent!) }
        if event != nil { sendEvent(event!) }

        if !running { break }

        updateWindows()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only repeat while `self.running`. That may explain why your app doesn't quit. If your app is configured to quit when its last window closes, it may also explain why your window doesn't close. The framework may not bother to separately close the window if the whole app is going to quit, anyway.

Comment: The problem is, what that does is not make it run. I cannot explicitly set `running` without calling `super.run()`

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I see that Apple's old [GLUT sample code](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/glut/Listings/GLUTApplication_m.html) resorted to directly setting the superclass's `_running` instance variable, which Swift probably won't allow. So, you could try using KVC to do it: `setValue(true, forKey:"running")`.

Comment: I've honestly never heard of that before, could you put that into a code sample? Pasting what you put doesn't work. -- Nevermind what I said, however it syill does not work.